# Trying to convert authentication provider from Python to C#

Tags: python, c#, .net

I'm trying to convert the following authentication provider to C#. It originates from this [URL](https://www.bit.com/docs/en-us/spot.html#signature-algorithm). I was able to convert the HMAC SHA256 and the hex converter calls, but not the part which sorts the parameter keys alphabetically, and join them with '&'. I'm not familiar with Python, so here is the question. How do I "translate" `encode_list` and `encode_object` to C#?

```py
#########
# Python code to calc BIT.COM API signature
#########
import hashlib
import hmac

def encode_list(self, item_list):
    list_val = []
    for item in item_list:
        obj_val = self.encode_object(item)
        list_val.append(obj_val)
    output = '&'.join(list_val)
    output = '[' + output + ']'
    return output

def encode_object(self, param_map):
    sorted_keys = sorted(param_map.keys())
    ret_list = []
    for key in sorted_keys:
        val = param_map[key]
        if isinstance(val, list):
            list_val = self.encode_list(val)
            ret_list.append(f'{key}={list_val}')
        elif isinstance(val, dict):
            # call encode_object recursively
            dict_val = self.encode_object(val)
            ret_list.append(f'{key}={dict_val}')
        elif isinstance(val, bool):
            bool_val = str(val).lower()
            ret_list.append(f'{key}={bool_val}')
        else:
            general_val = str(val)
            ret_list.append(f'{key}={general_val}')

    sorted_list = sorted(ret_list)
    output = '&'.join(sorted_list)
    return output

def get_signature(self, http_method, api_path, param_map):
    str_to_sign = api_path + '&' + self.encode_object(param_map)
    print('str_to_sign = ' + str_to_sign)
    sig = hmac.new(self.secret_key.encode('utf-8'), str_to_sign.encode('utf-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    return sig

#########
# END
#########
```

### C#

```cs
public static class AuthenticationHelper
{
    public static string Sign(string secretKey, string data)
    {
        using var hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey));
        var resultBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
        return BytesToHexString(resultBytes).ToLowerInvariant();
        //return BitConverter.ToString(resultBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();
    }

    private static string BytesToHexString(IEnumerable<byte> buffer)
    {
        return buffer.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, t) => current + t.ToString("X2"));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? You've shown two snippets of code that have possible divergent behaviors, but you haven't really asked a question. Please read [ask]
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [mre]

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, the question is how do I translate `encode_object` and `encode_list` in C#

Comment: `encode_list` looks pretty straightforward -- for each item in the list, you encode that item using `encode_object` and append the encoded string to a list. When you're done encoding all objects, you join the strings with an ampersand, and finally wrap this result in `[` and `]` before returning it. `encode_object` sorts all the keys in the dictionary, and then processes each value according to its type. What _specifically_ are you having trouble with? I doubt you're having trouble with [sorting the `Dictionary<>.Keys.ToList()` and joining (`String.Join`)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, something like that https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/hehasosefe.typescript?

Comment: Sure, that looks reasonable.